# ServiceNow GlideRecord sysparm_query Python

Tags: python, servicenow

Has anyone used the GlideRecord library for python? I can't seem to get it to perform some fairly basic functionality. I want to add a few `sysparm_query` parameters. This is just a code snippet, I had to manually edit it for security purposes. Hopefully I didn't introduce any typo errors.

```
for i in glide1, glide2:
    i.set_credentials('xxxx', 'xxxx')
    i.set_server("https://<instance>.service-now.com/")
    i.addQuery("active", "true")

def getIncidents(glide1):
    group = "mygroup"
    glide1.addQuery('assignment_group', group)

    print glide1.query_data['sysparm_query'] + '\n'
    print glide1.getQuery()[50:] #just to avoid too much output
```

gives me the output:

`active=true^assignment_group=mygroup`

`displayvalue=true&JSONv2&sysparm_record_count=100&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=`

I cannot get the query data to append. Perhaps I should look at doing the queries manually? Here is a link to the GlideRecord git:

[https://github.com/bazizi/ServiceNow_GlideRecord_API/blob/master/GlideRecord/**init**.py](https://github.com/bazizi/ServiceNow_GlideRecord_API/blob/master/GlideRecord/__init__.py)

Cheers, Arthur

Comment: Just to follow up on my own question in case anyone looks - it appears `getQuery()` doesn't return the `sysparm_query` data ever. It still returned the same even after I got a query working with parameters. Also - I never did manage to get `addQuery()` to take human-readable parameters (which are retuned if you add the `displayvalue=true` parameter. I just ended up manually getting the data string and hard-coding it in as it was sufficient for my use case: `glide1.addEncodedQuery('assignment_group=0f1fc35fb8c11010b834c3m6d6r4519a')`

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the getQuery() member function I had defined only returned the base query URL (not including the query itself). I had initially added this function for testing purposes, and wrongfully added this to the documentation.

I just fixed this issue and committed to the GitHub repository. Please pull from the git repository again or if you installed using PIP, run the following commands to re-install it from scratch:

```
pip uninstall GlideRecord
pip install GlideRecord
```

In terms of setting the assignment group by name, however, I still need to find out how ServiceNow hashes the assignment_group, or if there is another way this query can be added; That is, I have no fix for now.

Thanks

Behnam